# web api host on iis receiving zip problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

I have an app that received POST request with binary file zip. When I send using postman request with  txt file everything is fine but when I send zip file (with the same txt file inside and also using POSTMAN) then I receive IIS error:

```
 Exception type: ArgumentException      Exception message: '', hexadecimal value 0x03, is an invalid character.    at System.Xml.XmlEncodedRawTextWriter.WriteElementTextBlock(Char* pSrc, Char* pSrcEnd)     at System.Xml.XmlEncodedRawTextWriter.WriteString(String text)
```

It works fine on my local iis server. Do you have any idea what ma be an issue?

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare headers in first request between working and non working.  Then add/change headers in c# to match working postman.

Comment: it is the same, it works on my machine with the same headers but doesnt work on other environment (there is different iis)

Comment: FTP has two modes 1) Text 2) Binary.  Maybe the default mode is different.  Set the FTP mode to binary in your c# code.

Comment: it is http endpoint not ftp

Comment: FTP is really an http application (same as upload).  The default headers in c# may not be the same.  Microsoft keeps on changing defaults in different version of Net.  The server when you do not include the default may do different things.  The solution is to add the right header to indicate you are uploading binary (not text).  So you need to set the content type : ContentType = "multipart/form-data"